# Angular 11 - Reusable component not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to understand and implement REUSEABLE in concept in Angular. so trying to create reusable component `<mat-card>` which I want to use it
in different module's component.

so for I've created like below skeleton for reusability. But after the compilation I'm getting 'empTotalCount' **undefined** error.

Could someone tell me, the way i tried is wrong or the understanding about reusability with help of @Input() is wrong.?

Kindly someone suggest me proper implementation or any other approach for code reusability.

**EDITED**

1. create `generic-MAT-CARD`
2. use `generic-MAT-CARD` in my **target-component-1** with different data
3. use same `generic-MAT-CARD` in my **target-component-2** with different data

[MY Faulty Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8e9mdi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

(Note: same code working in my local but which is shows compilation err in stackblitz )

Infocard.ts

```
export interface Infocard {
    empCardHeader: string;  
    empTotalCount: string;
    
    empDirLbl: string;
    empDirectCount:string;
    
    empTempLbl: string;
    empTemprory:string;
    
    empDirStatus:string;
    empTempStatus:string;
}
```

### generic-card-component.html

```
<mat-card class="example-card mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
        <mat-card-title><span class="device-count">{{empInfo.empTotalCount}} </span>
            {{empInfo.empCardHeader}}</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>

    <mat-card-content>
        <div class="connected-device-info">
            <label class="device-status">{{empInfo.empDirLbl}} </label>
            <span class="device-count">{{empInfo.empDirectCount}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="offline-device-info">
            <label class="device-off-status">{{empInfo.empTempLbl}} </label>
            <span class="device-count">{{empInfo.empTemprory}}</span>
        </div>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions class="card-action">
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

### generic-card-component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Infocard } from './infocard';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-generic-card-layout',
  templateUrl: './generic-card-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./generic-card-layout.component.scss']
})
export class GenericCardLayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() empInfo: Infocard;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}


 module-1/myTarget1-component.html

 <app-generic-card-layout [empTotalCount] = "2" ></app-generic-card-layout>
  
 
 module-2/myTarget2-component.html

 <app-generic-card-layout [empTotalCount] = "2" ></app-generic-card-layout>
```

Thanks all

Comment: The component expects an object with name empInfo to be passed to the generic component, but you are not passing it.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky if you mean something like this   `<app-generic-card-layout [empTotalCount] = "empInfo.count" ></app-generic-card-layout>`.. but still am getting `Cannot read property 'count' of undefined`

Comment: No it’s expecting <app-generic-card-layout [empInfo]=“someObjectThatMatchesInterface”. You just got to match what you specified for Input decorator.

Comment: ahh.. i changed as you said .. now error gone.. but nothing displayed. this my source object in my  **module-1/myTarget1-component.ts** 


`empInfo = { count: 2, header: 'ADC Employees' };`

`<app-generic-card-layout [empTotalCount] = "empInfo.count" ></app-generic-card-layout>`

Comment: It’s not clear what you are actually passing, please make a stackblitz or similar showing what you have. In your last comment you still don’t pass the right thing.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I've created stackblitz and updated my question too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error because you are not providing the component the expected input with the expected name and expected structure. In your generic card component you specified an `@Input()` of:

```
@Input() empInfo: Infocard;
```

This means the component will expect to receive/bind a property with the name `empInfo` and a value of an object that has the structure you specified in the `interface Infocard`. In the current state of the component, if you try to pass any other custom property or if you pass `empInfo` that does not match the `interface Infocard`, it will give you an error.

Your example `MyTarget2Component`/`MyTarget2Component` would look something like instead:

Component:

```
// specify an object that matches structure of interface Infocard
empInfo: Infocard = {
  empTotalCount: '2',
  empCardHeader: 'ADC Employees',
  empDirectLbl: 'foo',
  empContractLbl: 'bar',
  empDirectCount: 'fizz',
  empContractCount: 'buzz'
};
```

Template:

```
// bind to property `empInfo` that matches the @Input() and matches interface `Infocard`
<app-generic-card [empInfo]="empInfo"></app-generic-card>
```

What you seem to be trying to do in your example is trying to pass individual properties of interface  `Infocard`. If you want to do that, instead of passing an object with those properties, you need to update your @Input() statements, angular will not destructure/unwrap those properties for you:

```
  @Input() empCardHeader: string;
  @Input() empTotalCount: string;

  @Input() empDirectLbl: string;
  @Input() empContractLbl: string;

  @Input() empDirectCount: string;
  @Input() empContractCount: string;
```

Here is a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bcg4vk) using the original `@Input()`.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Staroselsky , i was almost there. but YOU made it.. Now lesson learned. thanks again :)